# Change shortcut of ALT+` to switch between windows of the same app - not working

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz

I bought a keyboard which doesn't have the "``" character available, only through a key combination. The key above TAB is ESC, I would like to change ALT+` shortcut to ALT+ESC.

I tried doing so using Compiz Config -> Ubuntu Unity -> Switcher -> "Key to flip through windows in switcher". The shortcut appears to be recognized by Ubuntu because if I hold down Super, in the screen that appers is listed there as "Alt+Escape = Switches between windows of the same application". However, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Am using Ubuntu 16.04.02, Unity.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do this: Settings -> Keyboard -> search for "Switch windows of an application".
Set your preferred shortcut there.